# How to remove numeric input's spin button in R shiny?

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I would like to remove the spinner in the numeric input of shiny.

I have look up the code for it and find the following css code would work

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

However i would like to know where should I put the code in order to disable the spinner in shiny. Do I have to set up a new file for it and direct to my ui?

Besides, I have another project similar to this but using javascript to write the numeric input with data table as follow:

```
DT[["New Data"]]<-paste0('<input class="new_input" type="number" value="Row',1:nrow(DT),' id = new_',1:nrow(DT),'"><br>')
```

I would like to ask how to use the CSS to control the New Data Col. in the DT to disable the spinner?

Update:
I have found a way to define html class "no spinners " using CSS

```
.no-spinners [type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
}

.no-spinners::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.no-spinners::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

and the HTML code would be

```
<input type="number" class="no-spinners"/>
```

But things is how to put the CSS code link to shiny??

Comment: Update: got the solution finally.
Put the css file in the same directory can call it in the area you want the ui to appear, mainPanel in my case.
Ref: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html, method2